# How to do 2d vector movement

Tags: c#, vector, 2d

my onscreen object has a var rotation (in degrees).

how do i fix it so when i push up arrow it move forwards and not just x++ and y++?

Comment: I'd suggest you clarify your question, because its not clear at all what you are talking about.

Comment: He has an object that that face in any direction (in degrees) and he wants to move the object forward in the direction it is facing.  Right now he has the movement keys just to add and subtract from x and y

Comment: @pyro That's what I was thinking, but I wasn't sure enough to edit his question...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
x += sin(rotation) * speed;
y += cos(rotation) * speed;
```

But it depends on the orientation of your rotation. This code will work for rotation orientated up (north) at 0 degrees, moving clock-wise.

Comment: 0 degrees for north is not standard. In mathematics, 0 degrees is always to the right, increasing counter-clockwise.

Answer (score 8):

Not 100% sure that this is what you want, but I think you want to do:

```
x += speed * cos(angle);
y += speed * sin(angle);
```

Where `angle` is the rotation of your object, and `x` and `y` are its coordinates. `speed` is the speed of your object.

Comment: This is where 0 degrees starts right (east) at 0 degrees, moving counter clock-wise.

Comment: lol, our posts/comments are practically mirroring each other :P

Comment: You gave him the code without explaining why it works.  JasonX is obviously learning here and you are not helping by short cutting for him.

Answer (score 1):

Use trigonometry.

You have the angle and the length of movement (which is your hypotenuse) so you should be able to use sin or cos to calculate the amount of x and y movement required.

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify, since this is C#, you'd want to do this

```
double radians = (Math.PI/180)*angleInDegrees;
x += speed * Math.Cos(radians);
y += speed * Math.Sin(radians);
```

As other posters have mentioned, this is based on using trigonometry to apply a rotation to a speed vector (in this case, the 0 degrees vector is pointing to the right).